# Wordpress remove text and redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I want to configure 301 redirect in the WordPress site, accessing the below URL should redirect to

From
http://example.com/old/test-review
http://example.com/old/one-review

To
http://example.com/new/test
http://example.com/new/one

I have tried use regex in WordPress redirection plugin, but it is not working.

Comment: You add regex based redirection in .httaccess instead of WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using HTTP:// in the first URL,
try something like:

```
Redirect 301 /new/test http://example.com/new/one
```